# How to sign in using next auth given that I've already has the access_token from my Backend server?

Tags: next.js, oauth, next-auth

I already have an access token. How do I tell next auth to update its internal states (like update the status to "authenticated")?

I used the "update" function from useSession(), but it do not do anything when I am unauthenticated. But when I already authenticated, I can call the "update" function successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: using the CredentialsProvider

```
signIn("credentials", { accessToken: "abc", redirect: false })
```

then inside authorize function of CredentialsProvider

```
async authorize(credentials) {
  if(credentials?.accessToken){
   const user = {accessToken: credentials.accessToken, ...}
   return user
  }
}
```